# Microsoft Test Manager - Test Files Path

Tags: .net, visual-studio, microsoft-test-manager

I'm using Microsoft Test Manager to run my test on a VM.

Where are my test's assemblies stored on the VM while the test is being run?

[UPDATE:] It turns out the test's path is:

C:\Users*test-user*\AppData\Local\VSEQT\QTAgent*test-guid**machine-name*\Deployment

Comment: May I ask why do you want to know that? Is your tests affected by that somehow? Anyway, I don't know the answer but I suggest to use reflection inside your test and log the assemby's path.

Comment: Part of my test was supposed to run a console application I referenced. but it turns out the exe was not copied to the test VM because the MTM only copies references that are actively in use, so all I needed to to was to instantiate an object in the console app, and MTM copied it as it should.

Comment: I just found a way to change that path (if needed) by adding the following `"<add key="WorkingDirectory" value="<location to use>"/>"` inside the QTAgent.exe.config. I found that here: [Visual Studio Performance Testing Quick Reference Guide](http://vsptqrg.codeplex.com/releases/view/42484) which is a very useful reference.